# How to make required=false in Django registration custom fields for particular case

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-templates

I have override the `Django Registration app` and added some custom fields in signup form.

I have added feature that on selection of particular value, required field will hide. I am successful in it now I want to remove `required` for my particular field.

I have tried below and many other ways but on selection of value from dropdown, required field hide but on click `signup` button I get

[image]

my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $('#id_type').change(function(){

        var type = $(this).val();
        if(type === "dealer"){
            $('#id_dealership_name').show();
            $("label[for='id_dealership_name']").show();
        }
        else{
            $("#id_dealership_name").removeAttr("required")
            $('#id_dealership_name').hide();
            $("label[for='id_dealership_name']").hide();
        }
      });

  </script>
```

**EDIT 1**

form.py

```
class DealerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dealer
        exclude = ('user', 'site')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DealerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dealership_name'].required = False
```

**EDIT 2**

views.py

```
class DealerRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DealerRegistrationView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        RegistrationForm.base_fields.update(DealerForm.base_fields)

    form_class = RegistrationForm

    def register(self, form):
        new_user = super(DealerRegistrationView, self).register(form)

        if Site._meta.installed:
            site = Site.objects.get_current()
        if form.cleaned_data['type'] == "dealer":
            new_dealer = Dealer(
                user=new_user,
                site_id=site.id,
                whatsapp=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                dealership_name=form.cleaned_data['dealership_name'],
            ).save()
```

Comment: It is not sufficient to override the template (HTML); you actually need to override the form itself.

Comment: I have override the form and added some custom fields in it and now I want hide and make required=false for some fields based upon selection of `dropdown`.

Comment: It is better to make `required=False` at the form (.py) level and set `required` HTML attribute to `true` using JQuery in this case.

Comment: please see the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by making changes in **forms.py** and then applied `JavaScript` and it worked for me.

```
from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm, RegistrationFormUniqueEmail


class DealerForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    type = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=(
        ('dealer', 'Dealer'),
        ('marketing_agent', 'Marketing Agent'),
        ('private_seller', 'Private Seller'),
        ('virtual_dealer', 'Virtual Dealer')
    ))
    dealership_name = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50)
    subdomain_name = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50)
    banner_image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    logo_image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
```